# How to convert a Map to a List in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have a map in the following format that is populated at runtime.

```
  Map<String, List<VerificationDetail>>
```

I want to convert this to a List so that all values in Map are populated in the list. I tried with few approached but unable to populate the List with all the details available in the map.

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? What do you want in the list?

Comment: Can you use Java 8 or not?

Comment: @Burkhard  . I tried the following List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>((Collection<? extends Value>) finalMap.values());

Comment: @Louis. I cannot use Java 8 . using Java 6

Comment: `for (Map.Entry<String, List<VerificationDetail>> entry : map.entrySet())
   al.addAll(entry.getValue());` remember each `value` in your `map` is a `List`!

Comment: @Stalwart this isn't going to be a one-liner with base Java 6.

Comment: So you want to create a `List` of `List<VerificationDetail>` objects out of the `map` ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Should use `values()`, not `entrySet()`. ;-) `List<VerificationDetail> al = new ArrayList<VerificationDetail>(); for (List<VerificationDetail> values : map.values()) al.addAll(values);`

Comment: Thanks Andreas. If I want to associate the key of the map to a String in the VerificationDetail and populate the values in the map to a List<Values> within VerificationDetail? (I dont want to have the same keys repeated again within the list)

My List<VerificationDetail> will be like below

            VerificationDetail.java
            ************************
             String key; (Map's key)

              List<Values> - This will contain the map.values() associated with that particular key.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't a one-liner but I guess it does the job!

```
// Map that has the details
Map<String, List<VerificationDetail>> map = new HashMap<>(1);

// Meanwhile some values are added to the map . . .

// The list where all your map values going to be inserted
List<VerificationDetail> allDetails = new ArrayList<>(1);

for (Map.Entry<String, List<VerificationDetail>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    allDetails.addAll(entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be answering late but this could help someone else, there is better way in java 8 to do this,

```
Map<String, List<VerificationDetail>> map = new HashMap<>();

List<VerificationDetail> combinedList = new ArrayList<VerificationDetail>();

map.values().forEach(o-> combinedList.addAll(o));

System.out.println(combinedList);
```